# HTTP authentication - How do I make the user overwrite Authentication data?

Tags: http, authentication

I know I can't logout an HTTP authentication.

Overwriting through the `Location: http://logout:byebye@yourserver.example.com/` way seems to work on most browsers, except IE.

I was wondering however if I could let the users overwrite the Authentication data.

So say the user has some auth data in its browser, now they go to my /logout page, and it sends back the 401 headers so that the authentication window pops up and they can overwrite it.

**However**, when they click OK (auth data is now overwritten in the browser) the /logout page reloads, and there's no way for me to **validate** the new data because the page will reload after I clicked OK and it will run the Auth headers again and it will show the popup again.

So basically, how do I validate HTTP auth data if there's already some data set in the browser?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all. What exactly are you trying to do? What is the exact issue? Where does this authentication data come from? How is it "saved"? Where is it saved? How is it transferred to the server?

Comment: Using authentication information in an HTTP URL is not covered by any standard.

Comment: @Oded: Well, HTTP auth is pretty basic, all you have to do is set HTTP headers and all the data transfer is done by the browser. I'm sorry this isn't clear, but you probably need to have a pretty good grasp at how HTTP authentication works with most browsers to be able to understand the question.

Comment: @Gumbo, sure that's why I'm trying to let the user overwrite the data.

Comment: @Luca Matteis - I do know how HTTP auth works. What I don't understand is your question.

Comment: @Oded, sorry didn't mean to be rude. But why are you asking about data transfer, and where the data comes from? The issue is relative to the fact that when the user clicks OK the page reloads with the new AUTH data... but when the /logout page reloads the 401 is sent again and there's no way for me to validate the new data and NOT send 401... does that make sense?

Comment: So, you want the people who have logged out to stay logged out, even though they may still be sending a correct authentication token?

Comment: @Oded, sure. i just want to be able to validate the new HTTP auth data. and there's no way for me to validate it because the headers are sent again, and the Popup is shown again after they user clicks OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when they click OK (auth data is now overwritten in the browser) the /logout page reloads, and there's no way for me to validate the new data

You just have to reverse-validate the submitted data: if the user supplies proper auth, return the 401 response; if the user supplies bad auth or no auth, return a 200 or 302 to signal that the new bad/no auth has been accepted. The browser will then continue to use the bad/no auth for future requests.

Add directions something like “Click here and then enter no username or password and click OK” and you've got yourself a workable, if slightly shonky logout feature for HTTP Basic Auth.

(This is easy assuming you're spitting out the auth headers yourself from a script; it's not generally possible to pull off if you're using your web server's Authentication handling features.)

Comment: Wow, this is exactly what I was thinking of. I guess there isn't a better solution, thanks.

Comment: Indeed, Basic Auth is a bit messy in the rudimentary control it gives you over expiring logins, UI and Unicode. This is probably why cookie-based login schemes are much more widespread. (I tend to provide basic auth as fallback.)